# Helping getting string into an array so I can make it a list

Tags: php

I have a list of items in a string e.g.

```
$string=Digital SLR & Batteries (Spares if possible), Memory Cards (& Spares), Strong Walking Boots (No Trainers), Warm waterproof clothing, Packed lunch/evening meal (Or both) depending on workshop time, Drinks
```

I want all the items in an array so I can output them using a for loop into an html list.

How can I do this?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I see your data is separated by commas use [explode()](http://php.net/manual/en/function.explode.php):

```
$string_array = explode(",", $string);
```

Comment: thanks, I marked you as correct because you answered first but everyone else was too.

Answer (score 2):

```
$myArray = explode(',', $string);
```

You can use this for split a string into array

Answer (score 2):

Use:

```
 $pieces = explode(",", $string);
```

Here $pieces will be an array like

```
    $pieces[0]="Digital SLR & Batteries (Spares if possible)";
```

and so on

Answer (score 2):

You can use exlode() function:

```
<?
$string="Digital SLR & Batteries (Spares if possible), Memory Cards (& Spares), Strong Walking Boots (No Trainers), Warm waterproof clothing, Packed lunch/evening meal (Or both) depending on workshop time, Drinks";

$arr = explode(", ", $string);
foreach ($arr as $element) {
   print $element . "\n";
}
?>
```